# Dynamic menu in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating dynamic menu in MVC razor which is role based, I am getting list of menu items from database then saving it in session, then I have created a partial view for menu and passing this session in it. 
Its working fine, however I am not sure where to create this menu session?
This is my partial view

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">@item.GroupName<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                            @foreach (var sub_item in item.ChildPages)
                            {
                                <li><a href="@sub_item.Url">@sub_item.DisplayName </a></li>
                            }

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
```

This how I am getting menu

```
var lst = MenuHelper.GetMenu("logged_in_user_Id");
Session["Menu"]=lst;
```

and on my Layout Page, I am having this

```
 @Html.Partial("_Menu" , Session["Menu"] as List<Menu>);
```

I have tried adding the menu getting code in Global.asax Session_Start event but I am getting Session["Menu"] null on my layout page.
Where should I create the menu session after user  get login?

Comment: do the code in the method which hits first after login is successful. For example after the user login is a success you might redirect him to Home/Index so you can write the session code in the index action.

Answer (score 0):

`Session_Start` is fired whenever a user is new for your application, it has nothing to do with the login/logout-process. So your `Session["Menu"]` is `null` after login, because `Session_Start` was already executed before you logged in.

You should add that code to the `Login-Action`. If Login succeeded, load the menu to the Session.